# Tuple type vs. array-of-union-type

Tags: tuples, typescript1.4

I'm probably missing something silly here. I thought the tuple type `[string, number]` was roughly equivalent to the array-of-union type `(string | number)[]`, and that the following was therefore legal:

```
function lengths (xs: string[]): [string, number][] {
   return xs.map((x: string) => [x, x.length])
}
```

However tsc 1.4 complains:

```
Config.ts(127,11): error TS2322: Type '(string | number)[][]' is not assignable to type '[string, number][]'.
  Type '(string | number)[]' is not assignable to type '[string, number]'.
    Property '0' is missing in type '(string | number)[]'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

This answer courtesy Daniel Rosenwasser. You can get the behavior you want by giving your lambda a return type.

```
function lengths(xs: string[]): [string, number][] {
    return xs.map((x): [string, number] => [x, x.length]);
}
```

More information [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2189#issuecomment-76907232).